# How to distinct in Django with a field beyond a foreign key

Tags: django

In the following model relationship, how can we make it distinct in the B field?

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey("B")

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

The following will result in an error

```
A.objects.distinct('b__name')
```

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("b"."name") "a"."id", ...
```

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: I use postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **PostgreSQL** database only, you can specify the name of fields to which the **DISTINCT** should apply.

When you use **DISTINCT()** without field names, the database compares each field in each row when find which row are distinct. When you specify field names, the database will only compare the specified field names.

**But, When you specify field names, you must provide an order_by() in the QuerySet, and the fields in order_by() must start with the fields in distinct(), in the same order.**

```
A.objects.order_by('b__name').distinct('b__name')
```

In case of MYSQL, you cannot specify field names then you can use values().

```
A.objects.values('b__name').order_by('b__name').distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create A linked to specific B only once use the OneToOneField.

if you just want to filter for distinct values, then you need to order first, before applying distinct

`A.objects.order_by('b__name').distinct('b__name')`